# Blender won't save custom texture data to the blend file

Tags: python, texturing

I have an addon that creates texture data, adds a few custom properties and an image, but after saving there is no texture data is here. Blender 2.93

[image: text]

Comment: Okay, I see blender doesn't save textures that are "unused" but how to change it?

Comment: Outliner Editor > [Orphan Data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/editors/outliner/interface.html?highlight=orphan%20data) to click Fake User (x icon) .... alternatively if you don't care the file size ... External Data > Pack all into .blend

Comment: Thanks, it's working